# Minimal setup for bluetooth SDP in 2021

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I have minimal linux system (no GUI, raspberry pi like board, based on buildroot) which should be able to do the following:

- Allow all bluetooth clients to pair (no pin) after pressing a button for 60 seconds
- Allow connection using SPP (serial port profile)
- Endpoint of the SPP should be something like /dev/rfcomm

In an older version of buildroot (setup around 2016) I was able to do this using the following commands executed after the button press:

```
dbus-daemon &
bluetoothd --compat &
hciconfig hci0 up
hciconfig hci0 noauth
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
hciconfig hci0 class 0x080500
hciconfig hci0 name foobar
hciconfig hci0 piscan
sdptool add --channel=22 SP
rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 22
```

I could then pair from my android phone without pin and connect to the SPP interface using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal). Since then hciconfig, sdptool and rfcomm where [deprecated](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg69239.html). If I try the above method I can't pair from my phone (got connection refused). Without pairing the SPP stuff can't work obviously.

What would be the preferred way in 2021 to setup a headless system which behaves as described above?